# How to check which image listview contains?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm making a simple app with a custom listview and a database and I got stuck with checking which image a listview contains.

**Example of what I wanna do:**

If I want to update job1 then I click on job1 and it should open the dialog with the "under construction" selected.

job2 with done selected etc..

I wanna know how to make a check if list item contains "R.drawable.job_done"?

I know that this is not actual code but this is what I wanna do:

```
if(listviewItem.contains R.drawable.job_done){

radioButtonJobDoneFromUpdateDialog.setChecked(true);



}else if (listviewItem.contains R.drawable.job_under_construction){

radioButtonJobUnderconstructionFromUpdateDialog.setChecked(true);



}else if (listviewItem.contains R.drawable.job_incoming){


radioButtonJobIncomingFromUpdateDialog.setChecked(true);



}
```

Give me a simple example guys, tnx in advance.

**SOLVED!!!**

***I made a hidden textview and I saved the names of icons as strings and now I'm making checks with those strings. Anyway, tnx for trying to help guys.***

Custom listview adapter:

```
public class Business_custom_listView_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<BusinessObjects> {


Context context;
DatabaseHandler handler;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<BusinessObjects> data = new ArrayList<BusinessObjects>();

public Business_custom_listView_adapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<BusinessObjects> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ImageHolder holder = null;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ImageHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvJobListItemID);
        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ivJobStatusID);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ImageHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    BusinessObjects picture = data.get(position);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(picture.getNameOfTheJob());       
    byte[] outImage = picture.getImage();
    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
    Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
    holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(theImage);
    return row;
}


static class ImageHolder {
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
}
}
```

**Design of the app:**

[image: job status]

[image: listview with jobs]

Comment: you want to change drawable as per NameOfTheJob or vice versa?

Comment: no, I wanna make a check if listview item contains job done icon and then set the radio button to job done in a update dialog.

Comment: didn't my answer work ? Please accept my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way

```
  if (listviewItem.imgIcon.getDrawable() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.job_done)) {
                //do work here
     } else if (listviewItem.imgIcon.getDrawable() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.job_under_construction)) {
   //do work here
     } else if (listviewItem.imgIcon.getDrawable() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.job_incoming)) {
     //do work here
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please share some Code, so we can answer it :)

But generally, Recycler View is a better way than ListView !

If you do it with ListView you need to use a custom Adapter and Change the getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent). But if you don't post your code, I can't help you in your specific case

Comment: I updated the topic with custom adapter but I dont think that it will help since my problem is just a else if statement where I want to check which drawable is in the listview item